# Melt uneven data in columns and ignore NaNs using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

There must be an elegant way to do this but I have not found it yet. I have a large dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df
    Name    0           1           2        3      4   
1   apple   2016 W1     NaN         NaN      NaN    NaN 
2   orange  2016 W1     2017 W2     NaN      NaN    NaN 
3   banana  2016 W2     2017 W3     NaN      NaN    NaN  
4   pear    2016 W3     2016 W4     2016 W5  NaN    NaN
6   melon   2016 W2     2016 W4     2017 W5  2017 W6 2017 W7
```

And I want to melt the data such that there are only two columns `name` and `week`. So the result should look like this:

```
df_result

    Name    week       
    apple   2016 W1     
    orange  2016 W1
    orange  2017 W2     
    banana  2016 W2 
    banana  2017 W3
    pear    2016 W3    
    pear    2016 W4    
    ... etc.
```

What I'm stuck on is how to ignore the NaN values while being sure to not lose any values.

When I do `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'])` I'm not sure if the outcome is what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Op1

```
df.melt('Name').dropna().drop('variable',1)
Out[62]: 
      Name    value
0    apple  2016 W1
1   orange  2016 W1
2   banana  2016 W2
3     pear  2016 W3
4    melon  2016 W2
6   orange  2017 W2
7   banana  2017 W3
8     pear  2016 W4
9    melon  2016 W4
13    pear  2016 W5
14   melon  2017 W5
19   melon  2017 W6
24   melon  2017 W7
```

Op2

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',1)
Out[66]: 
      Name        0
0    apple  2016 W1
1   orange  2016 W1
2   orange  2017 W2
3   banana  2016 W2
4   banana  2017 W3
5     pear  2016 W3
6     pear  2016 W4
7     pear  2016 W5
8    melon  2016 W2
9    melon  2016 W4
10   melon  2017 W5
11   melon  2017 W6
12   melon  2017 W7
```

Op3

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name':df.Name.tolist()*5,'Value':np.concatenate(df.iloc[:,1:].values)}).dropna()
Out[69]: 
      Name    Value
0    apple  2016 W1
5    apple  2016 W1
6   orange  2017 W2
10   apple  2016 W2
11  orange  2017 W3
15   apple  2016 W3
16  orange  2016 W4
17  banana  2016 W5
20   apple  2016 W2
21  orange  2016 W4
22  banana  2017 W5
23    pear  2017 W6
24   melon  2017 W7
```

Comment: I like Op1 the best

Comment: @JAG2024 Yw~ :-), btw: consider the speed , op3 should be the fast

Answer (score 1):

Using stack

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(1,drop = True)

Name
apple     2016 W1
orange    2016 W1
orange    2017 W2
banana    2016 W2
banana    2017 W3
pear      2016 W3
pear      2016 W4
pear      2016 W5
melon     2016 W2
melon     2016 W4
melon     2017 W5
melon     2017 W6
melon     2017 W7
dtype: object
```

Or using melt with some cleaning

```
df.melt(id_vars='Name').sort_values('Name').dropna()
```